# Java project dependency on another project

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project (Proj1). In my java class I have to call method of another maven proj (proj2).

Here I get various compile time errors as that method is not available in my current project (proj1).
In order to resolve that I took whole method code and paste that method in my current java class.
Now that method is available in my project. But then that method again calls few other code from other classes which are again not available in my current project.
Again I needed to copy and paste all the dependent code from other classes.
This goes on and on and circular dependency is there so just wondered how I can resolve this error.
I have couple of options in order to resolve this.

1. Take source of all the classes from proj2 make a jar out of that and include that jar in my classpath
   **This solved few errors but then there are some classes from third party jars which still giving errors.**
2. Now I am planning for 2nd option in which I have pom.xml for proj2.
   I create build out of that. So that all the necessary jars will get downloaded from repository. 
   Output of this proj is again jar named proj2.jar.

**Now my question is**

1. If I include only proj2.jar in my code then will it resolve all the dependency?
2. OR I need to manually add all the jars in proj1 class-path which are there in proj2
3. OR I need to add src of proj2 as well as jars from proj2.jar?
4. OR is there any better way of doing this than the above mentioned options?

Comment: just add it as a dependency in your pom.xml, and maven will deal with it. That's basically what maven is for.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. So basically I just need to build project2, which will create proj2.jar and then add that jar file in proj1 classpath? Am I correct?

Comment: no. you just need to have your project2 in your repository, and tell the pom.xml of your other project that there is a dependency on your project2.
when building, it will get the project2 from the repository and add it to the local repository, ready for use

Comment: But you need to mvn deploy your project2 so that it is visible inside your local maven repository to be able to add the dependency in your project1 pom.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make all you projects use maven. Add pom.xml to the root of your project with following header(I don't know your packaging structure so `com.sachin` is placeholder. You can ask IDE to add maven support for you):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sachin</groupId>
    <artifactId>Proj2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>My Proj2</name>
```

Add same header for `Proj1` and add dependency from `Proj1` to `Proj2`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sachin</groupId>
    <artifactId>Proj2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

After `maven build` `Proj2` will be added as jar dependency to `Proj1`.

> if I include only proj2.jar in my code then will it resolve all the
>   dependency?

If your `proj2.jar` has `pom.xml` with **dependencies** that `proj2.jar` use - then **yes** they will be fetched during building of `proj1` using maven.

Official documentation about [Maven Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: Hey Rudziankoŭ thank you for your reply. You are right. Thanks again.

Comment: You have to execute mvn build on both projects. In the root directory where pom.xml is exist. After that check your local maven repository, find proj2.jar there. After that make sure your IDE or path "sys_var" knows about local repository location

Comment: Hi, I have used your method to configure the dependence successfully. Thanks very much. But I have a question. What's the difference of your method with "<parent>...</parent>"?