# How can I call methods from a different java project?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

It's as the title says. I'm trying to call methods defined in another Java project. Is there a way I can do that? I tried import statements but that didn't work.

EDIT:
So here is what is sitting in the code now in terms of imports:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOWX0.png)

and here are some of the functions I want to call that are in the other project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohzvb.png)

What I've tried is:

```
import com.example.cs320EthicsPlayer.api.*
```

but that doesn't work it just says import can't be resolved.

Where the 2 projects are located:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOuLa.png)
I'm not too familiar with mvn directories but we are using maven. The methods I want to call are from the cs320EthicsPlayer folder (project) and the file I'm calling it from is from partyinthebackend (another project). I haven't called on the other project at all, and that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Class Path for the file I'm trying to call the functions from:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEMNx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Otherwise these answers are just pretty random pokes in the dark.

Comment: Which IDE (if any) are you using? How have you setup the classpath for your application? How does the classpath of your application/project currently look? How does the workspace in your IDE look like (assuming you use an IDE)?

Comment: I'm using visual studio code and I'm not sure how to access the classpath. EDIT: just found it hold on please.

Comment: @BrainLag You might want to look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project on how to manage your java project in VS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a class Test inside a package com.example :

```
package com.example;
   public class Test {
    public static String getHalloWorld (){
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

All we need if we want to use our class Test in another package is to use import like that

```
import com.example.Test;

class OtherPackage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       
        String geeting = Test.getHalloWorld();
        System.out.println(geeting);
    }
}
```

You should remember anything you want to use in another package it should be public.

So just check where is the method, which package and class include the method you are trying to import.

Let's fix your problem now:
try

```
import com.example*
```

Now you import the whole package, but you should remember you can import and use just the public method from the package example.

**Update:**
I see you have updated your question again, and you want to use maven, I think that will answer your question :

[Java project dependency on another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610605/java-project-dependency-on-another-project)

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score -2):

If it is in the same project but different package you can just doing
import package name...
If it is a complete different project you can't import them. You need to re-insert the methods.